# Windows button appearance in a VB 2008 application

Tags: vb.net, button

I am creating a Win32-application in Visual Basic 2008. I would like to have a button in the form, with custom color (BackColor), on MouseEnter event. This works fine, but as you can see below, this custom color doesn't cover the whole area of the button. The button border remains as standard (Windows 7). Can I somehow have this color for the whole button? I don't want to use Flat button style, I prefer this Standard style, which has the normal Windows look.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, unless you go with a flat style then you are stuck with it - the button border is down to the current Windows theme.

Comment: As an alternate, you can use a LinkLabel. You would need to set the MinimumSize, TextAlign, and link colors. It would be more of a Windows 8, flat-button look, but the BackColor would fill to the corners.

Answer (score 0):

What I typically do is this I first gather two buttons that look similar, such as this Pic [A](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9vw63yxe23dvriy/Button.jpg?dl=0) and [B](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9vw63yxe23dvriy/Button.jpg?dl=0).
Then I will put in those two picture into my Resources.
After I begin coding the function such as the Example I have made down below.

Now their are two ways of going about this. There is a hover option as seen below:

```
 Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseHover
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Button1

End Sub
```

or there is this option which has way better response times when moving your mouse:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseEnter
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Button1
End Sub
```

Then you need this to set things back to normal:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseLeave
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Button
End Sub
```

Real simple code but in a realistics thats all you need! I typically hate the buttons! I find myself messing with the button look more then I actually code, really simple to just go to Photoshop and make a easy button that looks good!
I read your Question don't worry but to be honest that style button looks old fashion the buttons I made are more up to date and Modern!

Comment: *Never*, ever ask for upvotes. It is highly frowned upon, and may encourage users to actually *down*vote you instead.